# Serializing a many-to-many relationship to JSON and back

Tags: c#, json, json.net, many-to-many

I need some help with this one.  Google and the documentation of Json.net didn't help.

These are my objects:

```
[JsonObject(IsReference = true)]
public class Member
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Naam { get; set; }
    public virtual List<Dog> Dogs { get; set; }
}

[JsonObject(IsReference = true)]
public class Dog
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Naam { get; set; }
    public virtual List<Member> members { get; set; }
}
```

A dog can have multiple members and a member can have multiple dogs.
So I create my collections for both:

```
List<Member> members = new List<Member> { new Member { Id = 1, Naam = "James" } };
List<Dog> dogs = new List<Dog> { new Dog { Id = 2, Naam = "Fifi", members = new List<Member> { members[0] } } };
members[0].Dogs = new List<Dog> { dogs[0] };
```

At this point `members[0].Dogs` and `dogs[0]` have the same reference.

I want to save the lists to a JSON but keep the references.  I tried this:

```
string jsonMembers = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(members, Formatting.Indented, new JsonSerializerSettings { PreserveReferencesHandling = PreserveReferencesHandling.Objects });
string jsonDogs = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dogs, Formatting.Indented, new JsonSerializerSettings { PreserveReferencesHandling = PreserveReferencesHandling.Objects });
```

and back

```
members = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Member>>(jsonMembers, new JsonSerializerSettings { PreserveReferencesHandling = PreserveReferencesHandling.Objects });
dogs = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Dog>>(jsonDogs, new JsonSerializerSettings { PreserveReferencesHandling = PreserveReferencesHandling.Objects });
```

If I check the equality of `members[0].Dogs` and `dogs[0]` again, both have a different reference.  How can I make both have still the same reference after deserializing?

Answer (score 1):

You are serializing/deserializing dogs and members separately and have two JSON strings which are not related to each other.

Define single structure which contains both dogs and members, and serialize/deserialize all objects at once, deserialized structure should have single instance of each object.

```
public class Storage 
{
    public List<Dog> Dogs { get; set; }
    public List<Member> Members { get; set; }
}  


var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(storage, Formatting.Indented, new JsonSerializerSettings { PreserveReferencesHandling = PreserveReferencesHandling.Objects });

var storage2 = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Storage>(json, new JsonSerializerSettings { PreserveReferencesHandling = PreserveReferencesHandling.Objects });
```